# Kernel density of spatial data that's meaningful in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I have animal locations from a survey that I want to convert into a heatmap. My coordinates are in UTM [km]. I use `stat_density_2d()` in `ggplot()`. But, I don't know how to interpret the plotted levels. Preferably, I want actual densities or counts per km2. Something that is biologically meaningful. I looked into calculating the kernel densities outside of `ggplot()`, but this is where I'm stuck. I looked through other questions, but couldn't find an answer/explanation I understood. Preferably, I want to keep visualization to `ggplot`.

```
structure(list(northing = c(2310.17457679142, 2308.49604928213, 
2307.25399500842, 2307.34954129561, 2306.26391038052, 2304.55298697088, 
2305.37862926726, 2305.03055470454, 2308.78156014266, 2307.02328188916, 
2306.56787589877, 2305.1105159205, 2306.47531022101, 2304.52069380146, 
2305.75071605161, 2305.09715226661, 2302.97409158598, 2304.23789411813, 
2303.76384030457, 2303.47922899892, 2301.22556983046, 2300.90135831986, 
2300.57240841872, 2300.04196715051, 2302.16011482249, 2302.56429924306, 
2304.13427157956, 2303.29639148477, 2305.9254805512, 2301.31755530898, 
2301.61372558426, 2299.15379872212, 2300.67339060677, 2298.00588168102, 
2298.2210406308, 2310.98864695184, 2310.71158016183, 2309.97975005959, 
2309.96678258649, 2307.80999965824, 2308.41197401087, 2306.70725315944, 
2305.51340971656, 2306.10398696067, 2305.70214023439, 2305.39826072758, 
2305.46217707176, 2304.99553574422, 2307.32483682475, 2307.34776773372, 
2307.53857387771, 2306.8439347982, 2308.95813139391, 2308.16819294619, 
2308.95193090857, 2309.73224989645, 2310.16799697682, 2308.50764991477, 
2305.56145893812, 2306.78602891018, 2305.8811409133, 2305.71491901494, 
2304.94649503435, 2305.698768645, 2303.22940637431, 2305.69330692846, 
2305.42161163133, 2304.40477692756, 2304.12391473611, 2303.69929784348, 
2304.10122261974, 2302.81463414204, 2303.82250804213, 2302.2868430709, 
2303.64837722257, 2301.71554139606, 2302.47897973152, 2302.06361984974, 
2300.69669590835, 2299.82460131964, 2301.61049178447, 2299.43753152279, 
2299.69240604478, 2298.93291383534, 2301.47863672449, 2300.94400947531, 
2300.89623568505, 2299.09445308913, 2299.89465768217, 2302.25646385264, 
2303.09707196604, 2305.36564591079, 2302.40296347471, 2303.13630944588, 
2303.84186710889, 2303.09514005476, 2304.8399081219, 2305.00884947228, 
2305.17762704801, 2305.93988209315, 2304.65668022518, 2306.37948903452, 
2305.4672326314, 2303.42166084623, 2305.24308677022, 2304.66626051657, 
2304.60781517065, 2304.18967290159, 2304.05364504169, 2301.66045433584, 
2303.16712923818, 2303.20283275661, 2303.10736187866, 2302.38420512474, 
2299.8066598152, 2300.38311739418, 2300.50640980004, 2300.31866775257, 
2299.60066175512, 2299.84907164452, 2299.96334203358, 2298.92321775927, 
2298.21992245212, 2296.57262805333, 2298.18500804914, 2297.92193260721, 
2295.8058542034, 2295.70811267586, 2295.14624838869, 2296.95252228539, 
2294.00156016831, 2296.52621452306, 2296.66467227021, 2296.59902829563, 
2298.18907190381, 2298.47473796867, 2298.94432558532, 2298.36605653777, 
2298.95415997426, 2298.99227018498, 2298.52057737802, 2300.26285647428, 
2300.67990779595, 2301.110122044, 2299.9836735968, 2302.61540287271, 
2301.29050982593, 2299.74939557771, 2299.04939136111, 2300.44887320562, 
2300.3847356417, 2299.66234545123, 2299.32435869738, 2298.22712677222, 
2298.37422588801, 2298.03892354963, 2299.59895537829, 2298.82406417767, 
2298.69588587491, 2296.4441718446, 2298.01756053667, 2298.47957324086, 
2298.71294223127, 2298.19191515796, 2295.56934397638, 2297.87398372554, 
2296.5323035198, 2294.20158268902, 2294.88127553918, 2295.99470109353, 
2295.96437025972, 2295.6170142733, 2293.49364527887, 2295.71387632468, 
2293.01342613282, 2292.55981265261, 2294.39333694962, 2295.05612165794, 
2294.90161978513, 2295.63334582503, 2294.80581311699, 2296.13392606248, 
2296.02313811845, 2298.58970888726, 2297.44233717302, 2297.08558382355, 
2298.80643186742, 2299.2414848804, 2298.74545389396, 2298.1661187701, 
2298.88761116316, 2297.56641547089, 2301.44046775986, 2300.28496568999, 
2298.27691158656, 2299.97916209039, 2299.20726504173, 2298.4387441212, 
2298.60435431937, 2297.39146282914, 2295.855896147, 2297.99164576193, 
2298.29682056616, 2294.8296164399, 2296.19467067521, 2294.24255269506, 
2293.57156140063, 2295.76089014545, 2294.66383466939, 2294.05935420292, 
2296.90635280448, 2296.21462574687, 2295.63372401369, 2295.48558850983, 
2295.32058166569, 2295.59413394991, 2292.5990824365, 2295.74857316113, 
2294.88225804143, 2292.95632715434, 2296.00100637, 2293.05491312953, 
2295.86268240563, 2292.03743545168, 2294.87148743644, 2291.75613796477, 
2295.40956333246, 2295.13580098957, 2295.207850772, 2296.04663292178, 
2295.76237255665, 2296.53767202789, 2296.19203719864, 2296.7989726187, 
2297.11834888922, 2297.09778698306, 2297.75938437025, 2298.80183827453, 
2298.94575083649, 2298.54887087701, 2298.5393439566, 2299.43350432577, 
2299.8461465972, 2299.50032968105, 2299.47200033307, 2299.5026139242, 
2299.83888188005, 2300.07936703107, 2298.50938037802, 2299.0463897135, 
2297.52077948095, 2297.87089254308, 2297.4198222901, 2297.09642054889, 
2295.59129900388, 2296.11074369828, 2295.14238845643, 2296.15201239619, 
2294.55921460007, 2293.16727364729, 2294.34813498163, 2294.31807522076, 
2294.67515618604, 2295.58038306519, 2295.15814054633, 2296.64725841915, 
2296.89724319491, 2296.07224256297, 2296.52737290682, 2298.05966498856, 
2298.64058684296, 2298.49087975967, 2298.51638068006, 2298.8457462243, 
2298.71110860258, 2300.21042856117, 2300.11243434058, 2300.54874393474, 
2300.92731305295, 2301.06446252937, 2300.34069838447, 2303.74565311174, 
2302.21788576196, 2303.15682739426, 2303.9873115109, 2302.04791847142, 
2300.22862343878, 2301.19941513508, 2302.97221994449, 2302.15585808537, 
2302.79061235381, 2301.6642537358, 2299.42747937165, 2299.56675827606, 
2300.52291447249, 2299.14052792885, 2299.421108091, 2298.3237063779, 
2299.91213064289, 2299.92101391583, 2298.29342154409, 2300.00631892389, 
2297.95016965955, 2297.72004773071, 2299.78840787024, 2298.81159514588, 
2298.22736169115, 2299.01730964821, 2298.01337223755, 2297.66298771697, 
2298.08121782599, 2297.77710205108, 2297.08580190112, 2297.82198619494, 
2297.72934779414, 2297.23623393059, 2297.49454658849, 2296.48824261572, 
2298.02217111401, 2297.86686695372, 2298.63941705068, 2298.36434842651, 
2297.7853139958, 2298.99274356283, 2299.7409709818, 2300.42366772365, 
2300.55130278049, 2300.07687446961, 2299.95163770568, 2300.30148862925, 
2301.95692687983, 2303.18965144537, 2302.78074976477, 2303.14459990762, 
2303.11884286733, 2302.83652842732, 2305.58980970771, 2305.89284965437, 
2304.32173988626, 2305.47309497235, 2302.88118454284, 2305.23369679946, 
2306.10931596944, 2302.46147327967, 2304.50226869116, 2303.1901430977, 
2302.11295628622, 2303.02698322278, 2304.65294862818, 2304.41699818023, 
2303.31013728026, 2303.88131619151, 2303.56008351537, 2302.09060317058, 
2300.60793865225, 2302.04551976573, 2302.85238192329, 2302.11768646744, 
2299.73168688722, 2301.75379115663, 2299.14141776828, 2298.84940680322, 
2299.11465061153, 2300.28003566831, 2300.5111898404, 2299.61397640869, 
2301.54937262547, 2302.26093901361, 2302.98764157813, 2304.45714262958, 
2303.23996284963, 2304.56022224073, 2304.62503033328, 2303.46143052461, 
2305.8086939278, 2304.23030304826, 2304.80105234579, 2306.13584053734, 
2305.89131791577, 2309.12465318751, 2308.22001628289, 2308.0642424421, 
2306.38144543691, 2308.3188518468, 2307.1883742162, 2307.07572124495, 
2308.06714955465, 2305.56163284759, 2306.01034653464, 2303.97556228059, 
2305.38018051107, 2305.15627711839, 2305.84146561591, 2304.76721350995, 
2305.46454631121, 2305.37390998793, 2306.55625516368, 2305.80095057266, 
2308.76913784236, 2307.50498377962, 2308.28378740597, 2308.23403393579, 
2308.56844560117, 2308.80013822869, 2308.6403529184, 2312.43737194822, 
2312.10308454406, 2312.04392901774, 2311.69248922453, 2311.69248922453, 
2309.11855761452, 2309.30669542349, 2309.2828255061, 2309.21078445551, 
2309.44779287374, 2306.90777145941, 2306.13572374192, 2303.27016243878, 
2305.5541710695, 2308.04549110214, 2306.74548744836, 2307.86279730427, 
2309.15774498371, 2307.13644251373, 2306.85370780964, 2306.72718520503, 
2306.42611320573, 2305.80220971354, 2303.11788182509, 2303.66039762356, 
2301.55623995568, 2298.87479766353, 2300.59446989718, 2301.85708927104, 
2302.15730355671, 2302.60293176823, 2306.40942470354, 2305.2871775202, 
2301.79992935305, 2304.11918383011, 2302.82488095268, 2301.56672367924, 
2300.37258697919, 2300.71525138614, 2298.80108104371, 2299.69784704156, 
2299.19406055514, 2299.09789444253, 2297.48733776584, 2297.26536239094, 
2298.62427498583, 2297.81748436799, 2297.30376970588, 2297.77203287637, 
2294.7911700288, 2294.68352928165, 2293.8274886391, 2296.2461160853, 
2294.55793137563, 2294.1387428323, 2293.942388822, 2295.36753523377, 
2296.16670851723, 2297.30383054301, 2299.23747485666, 2295.17822472817, 
2295.16702054981, 2293.81074829268, 2293.39385463569, 2294.77610768154, 
2295.47257289273, 2294.86489765891, 2296.15514986544, 2301.19098265419, 
2300.12784605895, 2301.01527167738, 2300.07389609548, 2299.36099641891, 
2299.86206339444, 2297.16449950799, 2299.25570921877, 2299.84961327937, 
2296.55669517535, 2301.35584483563, 2299.76057526781, 2299.21445665407, 
2305.31014486266, 2304.7532878434, 2305.83235977536, 2302.91827231882, 
2305.46707091662, 2303.10166466621, 2302.04575248831, 2301.52904135831, 
2300.92426791762, 2302.54010703397, 2300.83687255157, 2300.80465703281, 
2301.79740668199, 2301.07633559478, 2300.25065950937, 2300.90406763444, 
2303.02766290714, 2301.92372712224, 2302.24902318153, 2302.83740058139, 
2303.97214602504, 2304.99836451199, 2306.86178393836, 2308.30987924566, 
2307.19324097778, 2307.00600056043, 2306.16394933247, 2306.27385525531, 
2304.08178547592, 2305.54149055676, 2305.31137189372, 2305.94766266139, 
2306.61427715617, 2308.74828063341, 2308.4515300069, 2310.52085867421, 
2311.14087225202, 2308.75948851088, 2306.53658355061, 2305.56376600063, 
2305.56175685547, 2306.50001458312, 2305.87943294812, 2305.59600146389, 
2308.82557956165, 2308.62302261486, 2306.1652493513, 2303.77302134114, 
2309.18390032408, 2310.83138355155, 2306.88196412856, 2305.62229885153, 
2305.87457931498, 2301.16903707471, 2302.83886809445, 2303.82355927492, 
2304.98701650721, 2303.16419684956, 2302.59190257212, 2302.782083487, 
2299.83510790668, 2299.49934677505, 2296.66141106907, 2297.31926327087, 
2296.69386597535, 2296.82319456005, 2296.91212393258, 2301.94238383824, 
2299.26553864626, 2298.00395709132, 2301.299579732, 2297.15326848685, 
2296.73604662718, 2294.63654000253, 2298.66745040825, 2297.28604432503, 
2295.69959167619, 2295.55872710475, 2291.99308608232, 2295.12101337523, 
2296.36894332376, 2298.60834722186, 2298.65887577855, 2297.47486996092, 
2298.91257989638, 2299.10874379064, 2294.28190519594, 2298.98503704449, 
2301.39945926584, 2302.46493594896, 2302.91771338123, 2303.00889832866, 
2306.53678206323, 2309.75997385742, 2305.26091995615, 2302.08561153761, 
2302.29137092369, 2302.53751518439, 2306.6666997244, 2301.69616510447, 
2302.18276553415, 2301.00565809257, 2300.20728797256, 2299.78442551309, 
2299.38580004804, 2296.76985802384), easting = c(738.482165850009, 
736.925072982672, 737.17923451551, 735.726595711455, 737.035099507127, 
736.911801943621, 734.30099378226, 737.722335776906, 739.136342477766, 
741.292969514134, 741.902188622531, 739.325338899903, 740.662030228298, 
740.655687000367, 739.546493058489, 740.17300109551, 739.565363128491, 
737.144509171633, 738.801269167646, 738.997691910368, 739.044819771859, 
739.102829327351, 737.639297382517, 740.068138988304, 739.305971528633, 
739.321699867509, 740.161541413554, 743.290612259443, 744.731168354749, 
743.078384232078, 740.918194397221, 742.836500995862, 739.521116243842, 
739.592278321081, 740.437220129573, 737.170238530149, 733.923458931022, 
738.430947225079, 735.527194967314, 734.168645562823, 737.024530947609, 
737.894141224878, 735.314852860151, 733.252785312381, 735.543175146494, 
734.249954327274, 734.880772259119, 738.873555397033, 735.857278673089, 
738.893108308139, 736.880412439432, 738.792164722981, 737.546038686653, 
738.961377480573, 741.887035824445, 739.469626348224, 739.486147147126, 
739.787386054128, 740.616314793357, 742.21123317622, 739.719032544977, 
741.291049009691, 739.386259449036, 738.10985348624, 739.847943176262, 
738.476893994423, 738.907043691817, 737.860841657617, 740.560394855904, 
739.229803222883, 737.580129439199, 738.429851863205, 736.809235265514, 
740.213557516716, 737.361817065507, 735.003001877512, 738.664065230399, 
738.201383428717, 739.179782845505, 736.200022605395, 734.153856249743, 
737.76927192306, 736.336621676605, 737.352228379945, 736.941240623918, 
736.340462816233, 737.267857839635, 737.878789765404, 736.301076372932, 
737.887348752224, 738.653450566777, 740.66537589653, 739.561564201176, 
739.298683205432, 739.959430763016, 742.669970577772, 740.525022960655, 
740.874968591694, 740.693624164988, 740.331377489019, 744.768282718874, 
743.222376175406, 743.540702654776, 744.029690323579, 743.196435305681, 
739.989434919718, 744.001918077509, 739.977818909073, 743.067947948377, 
742.267083409133, 743.678388714295, 740.476044365314, 742.524832990207, 
741.873275716905, 743.35170103655, 742.400492703989, 741.782944975437, 
739.750085604782, 740.830920233533, 739.14515778498, 740.036006152728, 
741.34878918245, 737.310317264783, 737.981194016942, 740.030984211786, 
740.240301160233, 739.795447094138, 741.510911652775, 738.595712968843, 
738.787641538306, 740.500276647034, 739.259041661914, 739.731889076444, 
740.715567831274, 739.763968773715, 740.082018002375, 740.035479042451, 
741.300903529784, 740.43669279971, 741.318599067626, 742.231471288463, 
745.280443195445, 742.875921848449, 743.188487136396, 746.368873092107, 
745.051564268851, 746.308074672089, 744.412357472171, 746.399647608726, 
743.381637404184, 745.669544936239, 745.63125495766, 742.881097589523, 
743.318108948969, 746.631859141361, 745.835475692527, 744.042016260562, 
745.530168693721, 742.215986664961, 743.411637298697, 745.756982516472, 
744.193569264747, 744.316196702725, 745.370389781482, 743.993426682164, 
745.099074907913, 743.955289814778, 744.951526095175, 742.207469356782, 
744.662722024135, 741.41506716567, 745.247313086175, 742.932042974672, 
741.231787712445, 745.166132670704, 741.455200889823, 742.513137757783, 
743.533513178144, 744.008701616994, 744.308746983295, 745.346439173116, 
747.330699777192, 745.467419303039, 743.917107461141, 745.924609783723, 
747.168399962098, 746.546035608681, 747.94579522275, 747.523615049804, 
750.923158362891, 748.807978050259, 750.077152944312, 748.948523418008, 
750.365989894853, 751.10274004292, 747.357992788864, 749.984246524391, 
750.392718715827, 749.633707083611, 747.29751651798, 750.048865869601, 
746.786488403968, 749.776197101434, 750.109716285371, 748.811338036726, 
749.75571317743, 748.572560339663, 747.921466509684, 748.504292279853, 
750.839185589188, 754.220397519415, 753.04128605195, 753.641253860725, 
753.023357604168, 752.666908353405, 751.434029239931, 751.146711919135, 
749.457050735334, 748.59151725767, 749.35039391911, 750.123947975299, 
749.150110464178, 748.96822650243, 750.258114476654, 746.959019531835, 
750.143500819024, 749.227827529746, 748.86952676952, 748.827586491635, 
748.707674650328, 749.074408259899, 748.461694917904, 747.763013324862, 
748.801051598657, 749.952721820114, 749.119234699373, 749.586176932973, 
749.164331201092, 748.823373218765, 749.236657283982, 749.122256108809, 
751.266160407826, 749.387997891735, 748.992933086224, 749.859083145207, 
748.801036920784, 748.512483326265, 746.191137899008, 748.598823179279, 
749.190072631867, 748.920070718054, 747.984936794552, 747.074420935742, 
747.514370022282, 744.537410382193, 745.939356407321, 745.517734455251, 
744.799110364876, 745.592676428237, 745.58653129168, 744.04757247173, 
742.788536050776, 744.812400173239, 743.648398120447, 743.305247569054, 
745.080764273125, 741.843029674534, 744.245313928394, 747.056567704649, 
744.765633214206, 744.527677908489, 745.59194880734, 746.224441687879, 
748.077749060408, 745.271495629499, 745.824312082084, 744.77880004375, 
744.673790409314, 745.581983385494, 744.461607878641, 748.685885024774, 
744.144438767421, 744.226409509489, 743.816319038023, 745.030750477929, 
745.519509614731, 744.676222367198, 745.854198241703, 744.55020348802, 
744.425083778541, 744.24375451982, 743.917193009722, 743.47118433157, 
742.270244984673, 743.753586307529, 744.050487274975, 743.478803298612, 
741.067796652191, 742.04263964684, 741.986862292295, 742.132434820299, 
741.526782529, 741.590172312105, 741.160477695551, 740.984754407981, 
740.960815960197, 741.162483224308, 740.944538152558, 741.207429496018, 
738.151810906223, 739.833460574999, 739.386216063709, 740.025190939541, 
739.06706275535, 739.260755108966, 737.930768943269, 738.614993570382, 
741.618293514406, 738.833807950391, 740.067004935694, 738.728081666028, 
741.526108082504, 740.556948574878, 738.713656211399, 740.130950796096, 
741.025189906047, 742.263185615439, 738.576659286313, 738.69059474152, 
739.792088178914, 740.533037835819, 741.723106790379, 742.049570312687, 
743.472309109692, 742.138354424273, 743.53012277362, 741.716984899422, 
742.48345732503, 744.351802123071, 742.851167449255, 742.125903010985, 
742.546766255144, 741.218130099017, 740.845473220276, 740.017797696674, 
741.487166216691, 742.437415159859, 740.891425052402, 739.903723232306, 
738.872922355904, 740.573485396305, 740.001032644456, 738.831877463612, 
740.390035611965, 738.217138890284, 738.603740046902, 735.610314417035, 
737.25846534682, 736.880109614568, 736.895781908778, 739.054783941934, 
738.618143963805, 736.081639252062, 736.91254367288, 735.853743940184, 
735.747350979679, 735.650922405549, 735.891433801935, 737.158770597161, 
737.632204133689, 737.768241786705, 735.193893611703, 736.407980468123, 
739.43908092983, 737.411765390514, 739.01069500745, 738.744286277586, 
738.194513124163, 738.263040989605, 736.729972092481, 738.129690239555, 
737.065466877414, 739.878580551745, 738.043860131114, 737.449693321215, 
737.009060008996, 737.335079768996, 737.99138471531, 734.088742964264, 
738.0481024565, 735.856142238348, 736.04364938528, 735.33569927823, 
735.856928828124, 734.081222427301, 737.693271341563, 734.89383825774, 
735.694437799644, 734.150533283837, 734.91096873744, 735.314629138019, 
736.60668727433, 735.81423428575, 735.556487170079, 736.862612145557, 
735.654432304637, 734.328531910647, 736.598575275582, 737.011087793728, 
737.011087793728, 734.667536650753, 736.126449768657, 736.721632033743, 
736.674403457907, 735.383274069339, 733.952481366537, 735.072001552654, 
734.990990715137, 734.83836318167, 733.666307276152, 737.170932014457, 
737.683618893882, 739.2506865524, 739.76416674483, 740.014555231991, 
740.140351217543, 735.641537190763, 737.567226406493, 736.571836005263, 
738.785628928913, 734.393885869502, 737.835055984679, 736.633400843401, 
738.111690491836, 739.938171480916, 741.998277791791, 740.093139924574, 
743.031209681612, 743.831427717087, 741.980431496927, 742.309655499078, 
742.41490605934, 743.833526350588, 741.820932631654, 738.972146362853, 
740.808277117894, 740.616496598959, 750.400153294447, 751.016382085964, 
750.823728584347, 748.796689893138, 750.218628923381, 749.02385673582, 
749.883261094857, 749.246552964764, 747.615893724214, 749.52735508101, 
749.675779191796, 749.13477238026, 749.326521783181, 748.822201981761, 
746.535898641875, 750.212787989213, 747.189817119373, 748.19483457763, 
746.589828602864, 745.191091778845, 744.517530223625, 744.604060954371, 
743.766446643317, 743.50779668694, 745.111639551125, 743.351451911455, 
745.711842449381, 747.33965676975, 744.497605744741, 742.699741415271, 
741.590051239722, 742.965669887075, 741.974681223493, 742.38271116112, 
740.972870196552, 737.358658568291, 741.431517351132, 740.203658941145, 
739.312714560839, 742.71387962076, 743.078680038849, 742.016130676817, 
743.007077842352, 741.325224357555, 741.949732918919, 742.309159060981, 
738.83100183446, 740.878863856449, 738.902465851756, 736.975369506608, 
739.065723280387, 737.295611040636, 736.046145650125, 737.246167238014, 
735.818866983373, 740.263791968729, 735.401795857557, 736.809791876225, 
737.486158958865, 736.883740682307, 738.225829293739, 739.180691670614, 
740.034144113727, 739.270940021771, 737.35177426667, 736.737432156475, 
736.942162662818, 735.573371938243, 737.071710988597, 736.339106953494, 
734.855523195663, 734.035727512479, 733.361166402886, 735.914542761384, 
733.744298478491, 736.548802242202, 738.626928870861, 738.122356608762, 
734.254043310202, 737.721677679858, 735.011472748678, 738.526461829603, 
734.507606696435, 734.868580021395, 736.016096304285, 738.858106489947, 
736.793193398876, 735.13934618889, 737.253064157254, 737.681888928016, 
738.448130832294, 736.889668002374, 735.81497846622, 738.646377588793, 
739.65353344378, 741.22738061768, 741.262254073908, 741.538896672405, 
742.720235070137, 741.796462996442, 741.892149633313, 740.895369075324, 
739.71470598429, 738.550098114644, 739.833824914042, 740.126871803751, 
741.249504084854, 743.783473236338, 745.119007876008, 745.894702592758, 
744.351469452717, 743.119463784919, 744.381368133935, 750.094804493881, 
747.140954788104, 753.236310840524, 752.981827456038, 749.185609343864, 
749.888015470956, 749.111998300408, 749.683006667118, 749.3104299562, 
750.315233153616, 748.463956404961, 748.408339039435, 745.609751867382, 
745.915894236833, 745.057169717881, 743.202570587476, 742.313270156311, 
739.256509222463, 738.66803720971, 736.422993980587, 737.88496488725, 
737.646707534825, 737.762742809044, 737.61037393126, 742.872327383012, 
746.095431614601, 745.547387058336, 745.719703660647, 745.36498012671, 
749.370302801889, 749.140650022374, 747.608149744434), group = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 2)), row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "13", 
"14", "15", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "38", "39", 
"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "310", "410", "5", "67", "72", 
"81", "11", "126", "145", "1510", "16", "181", "215", "221", 
"231", "241", "251", "271", "281", "29", "30", "311", "341", 
"351", "361", "381", "391", "401", "411", "421", "431", "441", 
"45", "461", "471", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
"55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", 
"66", "69", "71", "73", "74", "75", "78", "79", "80", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "87", "91", "92", "93", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"111", "112", "114", "115", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", 
"123", "124", "125", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", 
"133", "134", "135", "137", "138", "139", "140", "147", "148", 
"149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", 
"159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", 
"168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", 
"177", "178", "179", "180", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", 
"187", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
"197", "198", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", 
"207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "216", 
"219", "220", "312", "412", "510", "610", "710", "810", "910", 
"1010", "1110", "1210", "1310", "1410", "1511", "1710", "1810", 
"2011", "2110", "2210", "232", "248", "252", "261", "282", "291", 
"313", "321", "332", "342", "352", "362", "371", "382", "392", 
"402", "413", "451", "462", "472", "491", "511", "541", "571", 
"581", "591", "601", "611", "621", "631", "641", "651", "661", 
"68", "691", "701", "711", "721", "731", "741", "751", "77", 
"781", "791", "801", "811", "841", "851", "861", "871", "88", 
"89", "911", "931", "941", "951", "971", "981", "991", "1011", 
"1021", "1041", "1061", "1071", "1081", "1111", "1121", "1131", 
"1141", "1151", "1161", "1171", "1181", "1191", "1201", "1211", 
"1221", "1231", "1241", "1251", "1261", "1271", "1281", "1291", 
"1301", "1311", "1321", "1341", "1351", "1361", "1371", "1381", 
"1391", "1401", "1411", "1421", "1431", "1441", "1451", "1461", 
"1481", "1512", "1531", "1541", "1551", "1561", "1571", "1601", 
"1611", "1671", "1691", "1701", "1711", "1721", "1731", "1741", 
"1751", "1761", "1771", "1781", "1791", "1801", "1811", "1821", 
"1831", "1841", "1851", "1861", "1871", "1881", "1891", "1901", 
"1911", "1921", "1941", "1951", "1961", "1981", "2001", "2012", 
"2021", "2031", "2041", "2051", "2061", "2071", "2081", "2091", 
"2101", "2111", "2131", "2141", "2151", "2161", "217", "2191", 
"2201", "2211", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "229", 
"230", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", 
"2411", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", "247", "414", "512", 
"612", "712", "812", "912", "1212", "1312", "1513", "1812", "1910", 
"2013", "249", "262", "272", "283", "292", "302", "314", "333", 
"343", "353", "372", "393", "415", "423", "433", "452", "463", 
"473", "482", "492", "502", "513", "522", "532", "542", "592", 
"602", "613", "632", "642", "652", "662", "671", "692", "702", 
"713", "722", "732", "742", "416", "514", "614", "813", "913", 
"1013", "1113", "1213", "1514", "1612", "1712", "1813", "2213", 
"2310", "2410", "263", "273", "284", "293", "303", "323", "334", 
"354", "373", "384", "424", "453", "464", "474", "483", "493", 
"503", "515", "523", "543", "552", "562", "572", "593", "603", 
"615", "623", "653", "663", "682", "693", "703", "714", "752", 
"763", "772", "782", "792", "802", "814", "822", "832", "862", 
"872", "902", "922", "932", "316", "516", "616", "715", "815", 
"915", "1014", "1214", "1313", "1413", "1515", "1613", "1713", 
"1913", "2014", "2113", "2311", "264", "274", "294", "317", "324", 
"335", "344", "355", "364", "374", "385", "395", "405", "425", 
"435", "442", "484", "494", "504", "517", "544", "553", "573", 
"318", "419", "518", "716", "816", "916", "1114", "1215", "1314", 
"1516", "1614", "1814", "1914", "2215", "2412", "265", "319", 
"717", "917", "1315", "1414", "1714", "2016", "2216", "2312", 
"256", "286", "3110", "325"), class = "data.frame")
```

```
ggplot(dat, aes(easting,northing))+
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(level)), geom = "polygon", contour=T, contour_var='density', alpha=0.5)
```

[image: Density plot]

I do not know what the level values mean or how to interpret them. Nor how to convert it relative to km2.

Also,I have different surveys and I want to keep the levels consistent, so that the same colors in different plots mean the same thing.

Edit:

I understand that setting `contour_var="count"` weighs the density estimates by the number of observations, but in that case I still don't know how to interpret the different patterns below. If counts per km2 was just multiplying density by number of observations, shouldn't the two plots look the same?
I also don't understand why it's creating these artifacts.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(easting,northing))+
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(level)), geom = "polygon", contour=T, contour_var='density', alpha=0.5) +
  facet_wrap(.~group)
```

[image: Grouped plot]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(easting,northing))+
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(level)), geom = "polygon", contour=T, contour_var='count', alpha=0.5) +
  facet_wrap(.~group)
```

[image: Grouped plot by counts]

Comment: I think the values are simply proportion of the dataset per square kilometer.  To change it to counts per km^2, multiply by the total count, or use `contour_var = "count"`.  BTW, you missed a line or two in your code for the plot in the question.

Comment: Thank you, the code was there, but somehow it didn't show. Edited. When using ```contour_var='count'``` it's density*number of observations, i.e. weighted. It's not raw counts. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what "density" means in these contexts. But even with proportion of dataset, those values appear very small (0.7% for the highest level)

Comment: It's scaled by the count.  Density estimates are by definition weighted by the count, but the volume under the density is 1.  You have about 600 observations, so 0.7% is about 4 observations.  Do you really think there are areas in your data where you are averaging more than 4 observations per km^2?  You can round the raw data to integers and look at the counts for every cell; the biggest I see is 10 per cell, but that cell has several 1's and a zero as neighbours, so the 9 cell total there is 37, pretty close to the density times the dataset size.

Comment: Regarding the artifacts:  that really looks like a bug.  Maybe you should report it.  Regarding the differences:  I think the contours are drawn at round numbers, so those will be different on the different scales.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to understand. Would the levels remain counts per 1 km^2 even if I set h=5 (because my map units are km, I assume that equals 5 km) to be able to be consistent across multiple different surveys?

Comment: Yes, `h` sets the amount of smoothing, it doesn't affect the scale.  Bigger numbers average over bigger areas.  BTW, I think the artifacts go away if you force the plot to a bigger range, e.g. using `+xlim(730, 755) + ylim(2290, 2315)`.  (That worked for the ungrouped plot.  I didn't try the grouped one.)